# Invalid column name for SQL Server update-database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to populate a table of genres but continually get an error:

> Invalid column name

I have a simple class model for movie genres.

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A movie class is tied to the genre like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int  NumInStock { get; set; }
}
```

In my Nuget console, I run `add-migration` and it generated an empty `Genre` table for me with two columns, `Id` & `name`.

Then, I try and populate the genre table with this SQL query:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (1, Fantasy)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (2, Drama)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (3, Action-Adventure)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (4, Foreign)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (5, Horror)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (6, Romance)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (7, Crime)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (8, Thriller)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (9, Animated)");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (10, Western)");
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. if I put 'fantasy' in quotes (because it is maybe expecting a string?) then I receive this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Check your `Genres` table's definition, `Id` is a system generated column `Identity column`, without specifying `SET INDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`, you cannot insert your own values into this column even though they are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need the single quotes to insert string values.  From your error message, the `Id` column is an auto increment (identity) column.  So you can't explicitly define those values without setting `identity_insert`.

Easiest fix is to remove the `Id` from your insert and allow the database to maintain those values.  For example:

```
insert into genres (name) values ('Fantasy')
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Weird. I followed a tutorial earlier and they had me manually add the id's - which is why I tried to do it in this one.

Comment: @J.G.Sable When you added the migration, check to see if it created an Identity on the Id field.  The tutorial you followed may not have done that.  Glad it's working for you now though.

Comment: @J.G.Sable It's not weird - it's normal behavior. You just haven't learned the normal behavior yet. If a column is an identity column, then in normal circumstances you can't specify the value of the identity when inserting. So to resolve, don't insert the identity. Or turn identity inserting off, as shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2521/insert-into-sql-server-table-with-identity-column/). Or make the column not an Identity column.

Answer (score 1):

As other option you can turn on [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this table. It is allows explicit value to be inserted into the identity column of a table. 
And how was marked you should set string value in single quotes

```
Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genres ON");
Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Fantasy')");
.....
Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genres OFF");
```